# Modify a specific word in a specific tag in HTML content

Tags: php, dom, preg-replace

I'm working on an SEO project in PHP and wish to highlight a specific word in a piece of HTML content. The modification needs to be on a specific tag, i.e. `<p>` tag, and no others esp. heading tags (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.)
Also, I wish to not affect any HTML tag attributes if they contain the specific word to replace.

```
<h1>A **SPECIFIC_WORD** information</h1>
<p><img src="some_image.jpg" title="**SPECIFIC_WORD** some other words" />
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
into electronic typesetting, remaining <a href="#" title="some other words
**SPECIFIC_WORD** other words">essentially unchanged</a>. It was popularised
in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently **SPECIFIC_WORD** with desktop publishing software like Aldus
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

As you see SPECIFIC_WORD occurs at so many places but I want to match and modify the SPECIFIC_WORD that is in the paragraph text and not in any tag attribute or heading tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression for `" **SPECIFIC_WORD** "`. not for `"**SPECIFIC_WORD**"` be careful for keeping a space befor & after `**SPECIFIC_WORD**`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sumant but its not a matter of spaces before and after. What if the text starts with SPECIFIC_WORD? The matching with spaces will be unsuccessful. The **main** issue here is with tags, a certain word within a specific tag (<h1>) doesn't need to be changed, while it needs to be replaced in the rest of the text, in any other tag.